# IComparer or IEquatable or niether?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two different types, TypeA and TypeB, both of which are relatable in the sense that they describe the same concept but from different view points - though there exists a loose temporal relationship.

I want to create a utility method which tests to see if the two types I pass into the utility method are in fact related.

The objects are not directly equitable, but I thought that they might be Comparable (which they are),  however when I look at the description of ICompareable, it suggest that this should be implemented to assist sorting of arrays.

Is there a better interface to use, or should I just create my own comparer routine which does not implement any interface.  This is what I am going with for now, but I thought there might be a more pattern specific solution, hence the question.

Comment: `IComparable` is a subset of `IEquatable`. "Comparable" is meant not in the sense of "similar" but in the sense of "can be compared to decide which one is greater or smaller". Therefore, everything that is comparable is already equatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for an own solution, as neither `IComparer` nor `IEquatable` are matching your requirement.

Maybe just `bool IsRelatedTo()` instance method would be enough?